# What does the phrase 'in some way or other' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In this following context, what does the phrase 'in some way or other' mean?

Does this mean the same as 'in one way or other' or in one way or another'?

Should I use the word 'somehow' as its synonym?

Context:

> Even expected future feeling of happiness may, by thinking about it,
> become a mighty incentive, or inducement, to craving. Thus, whatever
> craving arises depends **in some way or other** on feeling, be it past,
> present, or even future feeling. Therefore it is said: “Through
> feeling craving is conditioned.”

Source: P. 37
''Fundamentals of Buddhism''
by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Comment: Yes, it means the same as _in one way or [an]other_.

Answer (score 0):

It is used when the writer either doesn't know the details in question, or feels they might be distracting to the reader were they to be included, but either way is happy that omitting them is acceptable and will not negatively impact the meaning.

It's often a polite way of hand-waving away, or dismissing questions that the reader might be expected to ask.

Examples of modern, colloquial versions of the same kind of thing include:

> It is possible for two photons to be light years apart but still be connected because...science.

> No, I can't meet you for dinner tomorrow, I just can't! Because...reasons!